# Error in Json, Passing the data to and fro, between python and powershell, using powershell script

Tags: python, json, powershell

I am trying to invoke python file using powershell and storing the output in a powershell object. When I am passing the same object in python, there is error coming which deserializing the object. Is there a way to deserialize it properly. Steps to reproduce :

Poweshell script :

```
$out = python .\python_script.py "1" "first Message"
#...
#Some code in powershell
python .\python_script.py "2" $out
```

python_script.py

```
import sys
import json

obj = {
    "new":"a",
    "fdsjkl" : "gap"
}
# print(sys.argv[1])
if sys.argv[1] == "1":
    print(json.dumps(obj))
elif sys.argv[1] == "2": 
    print(type(sys.argv[2]))
    print(sys.argv[2])
    print(json.loads(sys.argv[2])) # This line can not deserialize the object 
# Error is incorrect json formatting
```

Comment: a potential fix is to replace line ```print(json.dumps(obj)) ``` by ```print(json.dumps(json.dumps(obj)))```

Comment: What does `$out` and  `$out | Get-Member` show?